# ReorderableList - Seemingly forced to get element's SerializedProperty in a weird way

Tags: unity, c#, serialization, imgui, extension

I inherit from this and then make instances of the children:

```
public abstract class Connection : ScriptableObject
{
    public State nextState;
}
```

And then I hold those children in a list:

```
public class State : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Connection> connections;
}
```

And am making it look pretty in the inspector:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(State))] 
// If you are wondering why this is of State
// it's because state has multiple lists of different types that I want to render in the same way
public class StateDrawer : Editor
{
    SerializedProperty connectionsProp;
    ReorderableList connectionList;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        connectionsProp = serializedObject.FindProperty($"{nameof(State.connections)}");
        connectionList = DrawList<Connection>(connectionsName, connectionsProp);
    }

    private ReorderableList DrawList<T>(string name, SerializedProperty property)
    {
        ReorderableList list = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, property, true, true, true, true);
    
        list.drawElementCallback = (Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused) =>
        {
            SerializedProperty element = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
    
            // this displays a Connection from the list on State
            EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, element, GUIContent.none);
    
            // works great so far
        
            ...

// elsewhere

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
         serializedObject.Update();
         connectionList.DoLayoutList();
         serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
```

I thought the following would have worked, but it did not:

```
// Note: still inside drawElementCallback

SerializedProperty nextState = element.FindPropertyRelative("nextState");
EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, nextState);

// Output: nextState always null
```

Here is what actually worked:

```
// Note: still inside drawElementCallback

SerializedProperty thisConnectionProp = connectionsProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
Connection connectRealObj = thisConnectionProp.objectReferenceValue as Connection;
SerializedObject objRef = new SerializedObject(connectRealObj);

objRef.Update();

SerializedProperty testProp = objRef.FindProperty($"{nameof(Connection.nextState)}");

EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect,testProp);

objRef.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

The reference in editor works fine, values update and save through the various linked ScriptableObjects.
Why did the first way not work? Is my solution in danger of breaking a value at some point?